# How to read and use the String array using scanner class or other in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, foreach, java.util.scanner

How to read and use the String array using scanner class or other in java

i could read the String into array like that below

```
arr[0]="apple";
arr[1]="mango";
arr[2]="banana";
.
.
.
```

and soon

but in by using scanner class how it possible pls tell me

and any help full "for each" in java String arrays...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringReadAndWrite {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the length of String array");
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    String[] sarray=new String[n];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        System.out.println("enter the "+(i+1)+" String :");
        sarray[i]=sc.next();
    }
    System.out.println("Strings Entered by user:");

    for(String s:sarray){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To read into string array and then read the populated array you could use:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    // to populate string array`enter code here`
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int length = 10, pos = -1;
    String arr[] = new String[length];
    while(++pos < length){
      System.out.print("Enter string : ");
      arr[pos] = sc.nextLine();
    }

    // to read the already populated string array1
    for(String s: arr){
      System.out.println(s);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Program to read specific number of elements from the console and write them on the console.

```
public class Test {

      public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Enter string array size");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = in.nextInt();

        String[] arr = new String[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
          System.out.println("Enter next element");
          arr[j] = in.next();
        }

        for (String s : arr) {
          System.out.println("Next element[" + s+"]");
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringRWrite { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc1=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the length of String array");
        int n=sc1.nextInt();
        String[] larray=new String[n];

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.println("enter the "+(i+1)+" String :");
            larray[i]=sc1.next();
        }
        System.out.println("Strings Entered by user:");

        for(String s:larray){
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BasketballPlayers {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the number of basketball players");
    int numberOfPlayers = input.nextInt();
    String[] playersArray =new String[numberOfPlayers];

    for(int i=0;i< numberOfPlayers;i++){
        System.out.println("enter the "+(i+1)+" String :");
        playersArray[i]= input.next();
    }
    System.out.println("BasketBall Player names:");

    for(String s:playersArray){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You should improve your answer and add an explanation, how this solves the problem of the OP. Explain the algorithm, so people can adapt your code instead of copy/pasting it. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)